# How OAuth Refresh Token works at client side?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented Spring Oauth 2 server and added authorization to one of my service.
I want to understand,
when I am hitting :

```
localhost:9191/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=krish&password=kpass
```

I am getting response like this :

```
{
    "access_token": "24a20377-2ce7-4c6c-a65c-87adf443854b",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "39da80da-83bb-49e1-8e6a-8432428637ad",
    "expires_in": 59,
    "scope": "READ WRITE"
}
```

and I am using same access_token to authenticate my client like this :

```
localhost:8080/getName
Adding header :
Authorization : bearer 24a20377-2ce7-4c6c-a65c-87adf443854b
```

So my question is after 60 seconds (expiry time), how my client will get the new token with the help of refresh token? (I am assuming client is in the same session).
Is spring handling it internally with its libraries or anything we need to add in the server?
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client will send a **Refresh Token Grant** message, as described in [this article](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-tokens/use-refresh-tokens). In OAuth, grants are what get you tokens:

- You have implemented the Password Grant above
- Most UIs use the Authorization Code Grant after user logins
- The Refresh Token Grant is used for silent renewal, when access tokens expire

Grant messages are usually always POST requests to the token endpoint. Most people use an off the shelf Authorization Server that handles them for you, so you should not have to write the code yourself.

Comment: SO the client will automatically hit the HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("http://localhost:9191/oauth/token)
  .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
.body("grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=mobile&client_secret=pin&refresh_token=REFRESHTOKEN)
  .asString();
when the token is expired? and get the new token ?

Comment: Yes - typically the client will get a 401 response from the API when an access token expires. The client will then send the above refresh token grant message to get a new access token, then retry the API call. Here is some [example client code](https://github.com/gary-archer/authguidance.desktopsample.final/blob/master/src/api/client/apiClient.ts).